# on Django admin panal DetailsView can I do CRUD Operation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

I have django admin panal custom page. where I am displaying report of models. I want to apply crud on the report itself, but I don't know how.

```
class StudentView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'admin/Student/student/details.html'
    model = Student

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        student = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)['object']
        address_details = AddressDetails.objects.filter(student=student)
        educations = Education.objects.filter(student=student)

   
        kwargs['educations'] = educations

        print(self.request)

        if self.request.method == "POST":
            action = self.request.POST.get('action', '')

            student_form = StudentUpdateForm(self.request.POST, instance=student)
            if student_form.is_valid():
                student_form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student_detail', args=[student.pk]))

        return {
            **super().get_context_data(**kwargs),
            **admin.site.each_context(self.request),
            "opts": self.model._meta,
        }
```

I tried this but it return 405 status code.

Answer (score 0):

`if self.request.method == "POST":`

Doesn't apply here since you're using a class based view. You need to override/ create a post handler. If you want to return to the same page once your request has been handled you can use the get_context_data re-request your page context and redirect to your view.

```
def post(self):
    student_form = StudentUpdateForm(self.request.POST, instance=student)
    if student_form.is_valid():
        student_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student_detail', args=[student.pk]))
```

All of this aside you shouldn't need to override the post method if you are using django default admin panel. Instead you need to register your model in your 'admin.py' file within the django app, see their documentation on how to do this.
If you want custom forms of behaviour, then overriding their methods is a better way to tackle this in my opinion. But I do not know your use case

Comment: still it throws 405 code